# WebApi - Specify Content-Type in Uri

Tags: asp.net-web-api

You can use

```
AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
```

To enable media type to be specified as part of the uri as seen below

```
http://localhost/products.json
```

How can I get WebApi to allow me to post to this uri without having to specify a Content-Type header. I would like WebApi to use the extension to determine the Content-Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a server side message handler that parses the URI and sets the Content-Type header before it reaches the ApiController.

Comment: Correct. There is a link with more details http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers. e.g. section *Example: Adding a Custom Response Header*

Answer (score 2):

*Question*: Why would you want to specify the Content-Type in the Uri? Usually specifying the media type in the Uri is for GET kind of scenarios and where the user does not have a way to provide the `Accept` header. For example, in the browser address bar, one could enter `/products.json` or `/products.xml` to see the results.

For all other scenarios where you can make a request with headers, you should be sending them in regular way. Could you describe your scenario more?

*Edited*:

If you indeed are looking for GET requests, then you could do like in the following example:

- Register routes like below:

  ```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApiWithExtension2",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}"
          );

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApiWithExtension1",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}");

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
  ```
- If your application is hosted in IIS, then you would see errors in using the `.` character in the url. You can resolve this by having the following setting in Web.Config:
  `<system.webServer>

  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Comment: If the user does not have a way to provide the Accept header, how are they going to provide the Content-Type header ?

Comment: @kimsagro Most HttpClients will set the Content-Type automatically when sending content.